# Possible to virtualize NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 Graphics Card for Distributed Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, nvidia, video-card

I am running Windows 10 on Intel Core i7-8700 CPU with 16 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD and dedicated [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-1070/specifications) graphics card.

I plan to launch 3 Ubuntu instances hosted by my Windows 10 PC.
The Ubuntus will be running Distributed Tensorflow (tensorflow-gpu) code, that will using GPU for training a Neural Network. (to mention, already [I've tried the setup on Windows but failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52041077/10279258))

Q. **Shall my NVIDIA GPU be virtualized among those Virtual Machines or Not?**

- If YES, then is there any further configurations required to make this happen?
- If NOT, then is there any suggestions to build such experimental environment for Distributed Tensorflow?

N.B.

- I have read [this post saying VMs can not pass through host GPU](https://superuser.com/questions/779070/use-nvidia-gpu-from-virtualbox/1020250#1020250), specifically on Windows for CUDA. But is there any recent information available, ideally from NVIDIA side?
- Can anyone share some how-to follow in order to (possibly) virtualize GPU inside ESXI setup on Windows? Like there are several people talking [here that its possible and done](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/5m07h2/pci_passthrough_in_esxi_for_consumer_nvidia_cards/), although [not officially supported by NVIDIA](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032226/cuda-programming-and-performance/can-i-run-cuda-on-virtual-machine/).
- Alternatively, has anybody successfully implemented [this suggested solution for GPU pass through on Debian-based](https://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/how-to-setup-a-gaming-virtual-machine-with-gpu-passthrough-qemu-kvm-libvirt-and-vfio.1371980/) system?

Thanks.

Comment: I think your rig has not enough power. It's a pretty cheap configuration :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install tensorflow GPU version on VirtualBox Ubuntu OS. And host OS is windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345786/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-version-on-virtualbox-ubuntu-os-and-host-os-is-wi)

Comment: Thanks @Simo, I understand its very basic and I am not expecting to run this in production. I would be interested to know if it is technically possible to virtualize this graphics card or not?

Comment: @Simo Perhaps not for serious work but it's enough to get started

Comment: @ShakeelAnjum I mean, it's a great config but not for what you are looking for. I don't know how it will work on 3 virtualized Ubuntu, but in my humble opinion it will be "meh"
Anyway you could always give it a try :D

Comment: There is no supported way to use your GPU for TensorFlow in a virtualized OS with a Windows host (not supported by Nvidia, e.g. see [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032226/cuda-programming-and-performance/can-i-run-cuda-on-virtual-machine/)). The closest thing you can have is a Linux host with GPU-enabled Docker instances using [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) (not quite a virtual machine but probably close enough).

Comment: Thanks @jdehesa, I just found [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/5m07h2/pci_passthrough_in_esxi_for_consumer_nvidia_cards/) in the NVIDIA post you referred to. Though not officially supported but it's Possible to virtualize these consumer GPUs with ESXI setup, as told by several people there. I am going to look into the NVidia-docker you mentioned, but still not giving up with VMs :)

Comment: Thanks @JeremyVisser, I'm already using tensorflow-gpu as mentioned in the post you referred, and need your valued input to confirm if the GPU passthrough [discussed here](https://www.reddit.com/r/nvidia/comments/5m07h2/pci_passthrough_in_esxi_for_consumer_nvidia_cards/) is only for PCI or CUDA as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider @jdehesa's answer as for now there seems no way to virtulize GPU on Windows for Tensorflow. Thanks to @jdehesa

Comment: So I think he should write the answer expanding his comment.